# Can a Custom Connector work with a client_credentials grant flow?

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

I want my PowerApp to talk to one of our Web API endpoints on Azure that is set up for the OAuth "client credentials" grant flow. The security model for PowerApp connectors mandates that you let the PowerApp connector acquire the JWT token for you. This is a sensible architecture because it can force the call to the API to use the identity the user is logged in as. However, the "client credentials" flow uses a specific client id & client secret combination instead of the user's identity to generate the JWT token.

The only option to use in the Security tab of the Custom Connector appears to be "Generic Oauth 2". Unfortunately no combination of inputs has resulted in any change to the JWT token.  It continues to present the a JWT token filled with information about the user's identity.

What do I need to do to get my Custom Connector to make a request to get the client credentials from "https://login/microsoftonline.com/{a-guid}" instead of using the identity credentials?

Here's a redacted image of my Security settings if it will help.

[image]

Comment: Could you please have a try with change the `Authorization URL` from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/55..../oauth2/v2.0/token` to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/55..../oauth2/v2.0/authorize`

Comment: Thank you for responding. I changed the "Authorization URL" from "/token" to "/authorize" with no change to the results. It is still generating the same identity token.  Btw, I updated the title and description above to make my request more clear.

Comment: I know this is old but did this get solved or how did you work around it. I have the same issue our financial system has a oauth2 granttype client credential but requires us to read a key to generate a jwt token before request a token